# Loading classes only if function is called

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I have one FrontendController that get all requests from frontend. As all URLs are like:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'FrontendController@index');
```

I need to use the same controller to get all Entities. My FrontendController looks like this:

```
use Auth;
use App;
use Cache;
use URL;
use Redirect; 
use Session; 
use Response; 

use App\Country;
use App\I18n;
use App\User;
use App\CMS;
use App\CMSPageContent;
use App\Slugs;
use App\News;
...
...
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

I have several questions regarding this:

- Are ALL these services injected in each execution of FrontendController. Because maybe I'm loading the entire code and It will make my page load slow.
- If answer to previous question is yes, can I load a library only if one function is called?
- Is it a good way to solve the slug problem? Because all URLs have one piece only for SEO reasons and I don't know other way to treat the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies depending on how you are using the code. For example if you required the Auth login method, but nothing else, it would be a waste of resources to initialise a model or inject the model into that function.

For example say this is a function in my model

```
public function doSomething()
{
//Do stuff
}
```

I would like to call this function in my Controller. I have a few options, I could reference the model at the top of my controller

```
use App\MyModel;
```

I believe this doesn't actually initiate the model, it acts like a reference, so that when it is called, the system knows where to find it.

I could inject it into my function

```
public function myControllerFunction(\App\MyModel $model)
{
    return $model->doSomething();
}
```

This uses the most resources due to the model being assigned to the $model variable, which is fine if you need the models eloquent for database actions and its functions. If you require just one function from that model then a static call would use less resources.

In your model make the function static

```
public static function doSomething()
{

}
```

Then in your controller you can call it like this

```
public function myControllerFunction()
{
    return \App\MyModel::doSomething();
}
```

This would use the less resources and would clean up the code a bit as you wouldn't need to keep referencing your uses at the top of the controller